# codeigniter 2 forms in 1 view - only 1 form is working

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have this 2 forms in one view, but I'm confused because only the first form gets accepted every time I perform an action. When I choose to fill up the 2nd form, it redirects its path to the first form. The dropdown form works fine, but if I try to fill up the search form, it redirects to the dropdown function controller in the admin which is the (admin_randc_dropdresult()) instead of redirecting to the search function of the controller (admin_randc_search())I've been trying to solve this but I can't seem to find the problem. Any help will be much appreciated

This is the view where I included two views

```
<div class="table-responsive">
         <table border='1'>
            <tr>
              <td>
             <?php include 'randc_dropdown.php';?>
             </td>

              <td>
             <?php include 'randc_search.php'; ?>
              </td>
           </tr>
         </table>
       </div>
```

first view

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/admin_randc_dropdresult'); ?>
<?php $options = array('0' => 'Choose Option',
                          '1'  => 'Garden Plaza',
                          '2'    => 'Cafe Treveno',
                        );
                ?>
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_label("Select Restaurant:",'class="form-control"'); ?>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_dropdown('restos', $options, '0', 'class="form-control"');?>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_submit('admin_randc_dropdresult','Go','class="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="dropdown" id="Go"');?>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<?php form_close();?>
```

2nd view:

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/admin_randc_search'); ?>

        <table border='1'>
            <tr>
                <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php echo form_input('resto_name','','placeholder="Restaurant Name"','class="form-control"'); ?>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <?php echo form_submit('Submit','Search','class="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="Search" id="Search"');?>
                        </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

<?php form_close();?>
```

Here's my controller

```
public function admin_randc_dropdresult()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data2['username'] = $session_data['username'];

        $options = array(
              '0'  => 'Choose option',
              '1'  => 'Garden Plaza',
              '2'    => 'Cafe Treveno',
            );
        $key = $this->input->post('restos');
        $value = $options[$key];

        $data['rc'] = $this->randc_model->randc_dropdown($value);
        $this->load->view('rates_comments/randc_dropdownresult',array_merge( $data2,$data));
    }
}
public function admin_randc_search()
{
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {

            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data2['username'] = $session_data['username'];

        $resto_name = $this->input->post('resto_name');

        $data['rc'] = $this->randc_model->search_randc_specific($resto_name);
        $this->load->view('rates_comments/randc_searchresult',array_merge( $data2,$data));

    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't just a CodeIgniter thing. 2 forms on a page is tricky in general. Try having them both submit to the same URL and having a single controller action figure out which form was submitted.

Comment: That's what I did at first before I separated the views. Will try to do that again now. Thanks! @mopo922

Comment: I totally understand trying to separate. Might be more trouble than it's worth, though! Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can still keep the views separated and while keeping one controller:

```
 if($this->input->post('submit_btn_name') === 'submit_value'){

        $options = array(
          '0'  => 'Choose option',
          '1'  => 'Garden Plaza',
          '2'    => 'Cafe Treveno',
        );
     $key = $this->input->post('restos');
     $value = $options[$key];

     $data['rc'] = $this->randc_model->randc_dropdown($value);
     $this->load->view('rates_comments/randc_dropdownresult',array_merge( $data2,$data)
   }

 elseif($this->input->post('other_btn) ==='other_submit'){

      $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
      $data2['username'] = $session_data['username'];

      $resto_name = $this->input->post('resto_name');

      $data['rc'] = $this->randc_model->search_randc_specific($resto_name);
      $this->load->view('rates_comments/randc_searchresult',array_merge( $data2,$data);
 }
```

Comment: This also works, but what I forgot was to echo the form_close(). Thank you so much for all your responses!

Answer (score 0):

is it because you are not echoing the form close?
that could mess up the separation of the forms because the first form would not close properly

```
<?php form_close();?>
```

should it be this?

```
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: Settled to putting them in 1 controller but when I tried this, man it worked like a charm. Thank you so much!!! @cartalot